# After upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10, gnome-shell entry in Lightdm actually launched Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, lightdm

I had Ubuntu 11.04 installed running gnome 2. I upgraded to 11.10 and everything went very smoothly. I installed GNOME Shell via:

```
sudo aptitude install gnome-shell
```

Logging into the Gnome session from Lightdm only launches Unity. I tried reinstalling gnome-shell and reconfiguring the gnome-session package to get it to rebuild the Lightdm .desktop files to no avail.

Comment: If a full restart hasn't fixed then you first may want to determine if you're getting unity-3d or unity-2d. If not sure this command will tell you, ubuntu means 3d. Run without the quotes, " echo $DESKTOP_SESSION "

Comment: It's very strange. When I run the gnome session the $DESKTOP_SESSION output gnome-shell even though unity is clearly running. Yes, I am running unity 3d when logging into Ubuntu session.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)